# iterate through list of id as parameter in API call

Tags: python-3.x, api

I've got a series of API calls I've built, but I am new to it and now need to iterate through a list of ID's, pull all their data, and then move on to the next id. I'm stuck. The base structure of the API call is below. How do I iterate through the list of id's as a parameter?

```
url = "https://api.url.com/data"
id_list = [1, 2, 3]
querystring = {"id": ????
            ,"startTime":"1627689600000"
            ,"endTime":"1627732800000"}
```

Comment: `for id in id_list: querystring = {"id": id, "startTime": ...} ...`

Comment: of course. I had the "for" clause in the wrong place. Thanks @GreenCloakGuy